# Trying to set full directory path in terminal, but \u cannot be recognized in ~/.zshrc

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

I tried to set full directory path shown at terminal as suggested in the following link, and I modified  ~/.zshrc by adding the following line. After source ~/.zshrc, it looks like zshrc cannot recognize \u, \H, \w.

https://superuser.com/questions/239994/how-to-have-full-directory-path-always-shown-in-mac-terminal-like-linux-termina

So how can I fix it?

```
Added this line into ~/.zshrc:
    export PS1='\u@\H [\w]$ '
The terminal looks like:
    \u@\H [\w]$
```

Comment: `zsh` uses different escape sequences than `bash`. Search for `SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES` in `man zshmisc`.

Comment: Thanks chepner, and I think I figured it out.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't be using `export` here. That puts the new `PS1` value into the environment, which means other shells in the process tree will try to use it even if they aren't zsh.

Comment: Also, don't edit an answer into the question; instead, add your own answer **as a separate answer**, using the "add an answer" button.

Comment: Charles Duffy, can you help me modify my command? currently I am using krzyk's.

Comment: krzyk's answer is a fine one -- if it's what you're going with, you might click the checkbox next to it

Answer (score 4):

Use `PROMPT` variable (http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) and %n, %m and %d:

```
PROMPT='%n@%m [%d]$ '
```

Comment: Is there a reason to encourage `export` for this? This isn't as hazardous as for `PS1`, where non-zsh shells will try to use the value if they inherit it, but I'm not sure if there's actually value added.

Comment: Author had it so I left it there.